# Use embedded font in Windows Store App

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, embedded-fonts

I would like to use [Anonymous Pro](http://www.ms-studio.com/FontSales/anonymouspro.html) font in a Windows RT application. I was trying to follow the steps from [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/8019a0ac-77ef-4ebb-83f3-87b6c521625d/), but without any success.

This is my try:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="56"
           FontFamily="/Assets/Fonts/Anonymous Pro.ttf"
           />
```

Instead of Anonymous Pro the default font is used. Actually, it the sample (see the link) the font family is specified, but I'm not sure: should I do it or should not. If I should, which family should be there?

So how to embed custom font in Windows RT application and use it from there?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

here you go.. just appened the font name.. blogged about it when i saw you post
http://invokeit.wordpress.com/2012/10/18/embed-use-custom-font-in-windows-8-store-apps-win8dev-winrt/

Comment: Although I've done this, the PC is not recognising the embedded font until i manually install it on the PC.

Comment: Edit: I think I fixed that issue. Include them as "content" was the key.

Comment: Not working for me unless initial "/" is there! (at the beginning of the path to the font file)